# Java local variable

Tags: java

This is a question about java local variables (Following code in the same method)

```
boolean userWantsToSave;
userWantsToSave = true;
```

Eclipse throws The value of the local variable userWantsToSave is not used, my question is why?

Since the variable is assigned true, why is it still not used?

Comment: Assigning a variable and never reading it is not using it. Eclipse is correct.

Comment: you'd have to use the variable if you wanted that to go away. like if(userWantsToSave){//doSomeCrazyStuff}

Comment: add a `System.out.println(userWantsToSave);` for example and the warning will disappear, i.e. use the variable, in this case just printing its value to the console.

Comment: Think of a variable as a parking space for a value of some kind.  The assignment says what should be in the parking space.  But even if you've got a car in your parking space, you haven't used it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned a value to it, but you never used the value of `usertWantsToSave`

```
if(usertWantsToSave){ // You read the value of usertWantsToSave. You used it
   save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use it in a if (userWantsToSave) or something else. Using is reading the variable somewhere. Assigning a value is just that, it is not used because of that.

Comment: Why is if (userWantsToSave = true) not a use of the variable?

Comment: Because if you removed it the program would still be the same. That line makes no difference to the program at all.

Comment: @user2177940 `userWantsToSave = true` is assignment, use `==`  to compaire.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a real world example:
lets say a parent x have two kids names a and b and x had got two sweets from market. Now x will give one sweet each to his/her kids. "This is just assignment" but both of these a and b have not eaten those sweets. "That's where it's not used"